# FoxPro sometime doesn't find files in the LAN

Tags: networking, visual-foxpro

Sometimes a visual FoxPro App doesn't find files in a FileShare, which are there.

for example when checking in a loop File() on a existing file on a Network share about 5% of the tries don't find the file.

This works on most machines but sometimes it doesn't work. In the curren scenario I've a Windows Server 2K8 as file server (perhaps a SMB2 issue?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would patch your 2K8 server to SP1 (and any Windows 7 clients too), this will take care of any SMB2 issues. Those issues were around CDX index file corruption, though.

It's also possible that this is due to the caching that SMB2 uses, which can produce 'File Not Found' errors. The client registry settings involved are:

```
FileInfoCacheLifetime
FileNotFoundCacheLifetime
DirectoryCacheLifetime
```

There is a discussion regarding this on [Alaska Software's](http://www.alaska-software.com/fixes/smb2/overview.shtm#download) website, and a useful MSI installer which can be run per workstation to adjust the settings. This company produces a product called Xbase++ but I would guess it is close enough to Visual FoxPro in terms of low-level file IO and locking.

Comment: Deactivating SMB2 worked . Not a good solution but as I see it the only one. In the meanwhile I found some more sources on the web with the same problem :-(

Answer (score 2):

Not positive if its an issue of Fox, or your network. Going way back in time, I had a client that had problems somewhat similar.  Took Foxpro out of the equation and just used Windows Explorer and it would hang for a moment.  It ended up that their network cards were set to energy saving mode and would basically time-out / shut down due to inactivity.  The network drive share would apparently be released.  Until the network card would re-connect and get established again, they had issues.  By changing so the network card NEVER went into energy save mode, problem went away for them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I have versions of fox pro deployed on various different servers, with various versions of windows server and never experienced an issue as described.

Maybe you could try a similar test using a different programming discipline, .Net , access, Ruby ...., etc

Post you test loop, just out of interest ?